# T-SQL: @variable | inner join | 2 database

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2 - 2 database in the instance, `Mandant_2` and `tlock`.

I need a inner join SQL command between the databases with `@variable`:

```
    DECLARE @t AS TABLE (
        c VARCHAR(100)
    )

    INSERT @t VALUES ('[Mandant_2].[dbo].[tartikel]')

UPDATE tlock.dbo.temp SET Warengruppe = a.kWarengruppe
FROM tlock.dbo.temp d
INNER JOIN @t a ON d.HAN = a.cHAN
```

I get an error:

> Message 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spMyStoreProduced, line 39
>   Invalid column name 'cHAN'.

Unfortunately I have no idea why.

Thanks

Comment: I guess the join condition should be `d.HAN = a.HAN` in the last row.

Answer (score 0):

What does mean last line in your code

```
INNER JOIN @t a ON d.HAN = a.cHAN
```

Table @t has column named c, but there is no column named cHAN.
Did you mean to say

```
INNER JOIN @t a ON d.HAN = a.c
```

**Proof of concept:**

just try this

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE (
c VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT @t VALUES ('[Mandant_2].[dbo].[tartikel]')

select cHAN from @T
```

and you will get

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'cHAN'.
```